# Codeigniter db queries is not capturing some specific queries

Tags: codeigniter

am trying to capture all queries and record a log of interactions, however some queries are not being captured, this specific query for example:

```
$this->db->update('showtec.motoristas', $motorista);
```

I capture the queries using the Hooks function like this:
Hooks.php:

```
$hook['post_controller'] = array(
    'class' => 'Db_query_log',
    'function' => 'log_db_queries',
    'filename' => 'db_log.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

db_log.php:

```
    <?php

class Db_query_log {

    function __construct() {
    }

    function log_db_queries() {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->model('auditoria');
        $data = array();

        $queries = $CI->db->queries;
        $data['id_usuario_gestor'] = $CI->auth->get_login('id_user');

        foreach ($queries as $query){
            if (preg_match($pattern = '/' . 'INSERT' . '/', $query)){
                $queryArray = explode("`", $query);
                if($queryArray[3] != 'ip'){
                    $data['query'] = $query;
                    $data['clause'] = 'insert';
                    break;
                }
            }elseif (preg_match($pattern = '/' . 'UPDATE' . '/', $query)){
                $data['query'] = $query;
                $data['clause'] = 'update';
                break;
            }elseif (preg_match($pattern = '/' . 'DELETE' . '/', $query)){
                $data['query'] = $query;
                $data['clause'] = 'delete';
                break;
            }
        }

        if(array_key_exists('query', $data)){
            $CI->auditoria->salvarAuditoria($data);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't even understand how this code works - you iterate over your queries - but in your `$data` array is only the last item of your iteration because you dont store them as an array

Comment: The function "db-> queries takes queries that are currently being executed, I use the hook" post_controller "to get there, all my queries are being captured normally, except the one described in the problem, it does not appear in" db- > queries ".